# php json read file

Tags: php, json

storage.json :

```
{"544aee0b0a00f":{"p_name":"testname","p_about":null,"file":"images\/1.png"}}
{"548afbeb42afe":{"p_name":"testname2","p_about":null,"file":"images\/2.png"}}
{"549afc8c8890f":{"p_name":"testname3","p_about":null,"file":"images\/3.jpg"}}
```

Now the numbers with letters at the beginning are uniqid() function that been called when writing items to the file.

```
<?php
$storage_file = 'storage.json';
$storage = file_get_contents($storage_file);
$storage = json_decode($storage,true);
$storage = empty($storage) ? array() : $storage;
print_r($storage)
?>
```

Now i have tried to display all records from the json file but it works ONLY if i have 1 record in file, if i have more than 1 , for like here about ( 3 records ) than the result i get is simple text: Array()

Could anybody help me out ? I'm kinda stuck over here, no idea what to do to fix the issue

Comment: You have invalid JSON.  It's not at all surprising that it's giving you trouble.  :P

Comment: When you have multiple JSON objects, they must be grouped in a JSON array. Something like `[{...},{...},{...}]`. Your `storage.json` is not actually a valid JSON file. Your issue comes from the code that "writes items to the file" (why aren't you using a database?)

Comment: it is , its just the [] been replaced $new_id = count($storage);
$uid = uniqid(); 
$storage[$uid] = $new_record;
file_put_contents($storage_file,json_encode($storage), FILE_APPEND);

Comment: @EvilNabster: You can't just tack new JSON onto the end of the file like that.  (Well, you can, but you should also *expect* a JSON parser to choke on it.)  A string of JSON must represent one thing (which might end up being a tree of things, but has a single root).

Comment: @EvilNabster No, you missed the point. You're storing a separate JSON of `$storage` for each object as a line in the file. That's not valid JSON.

Comment: I'm  late, but I add some useful answer with `file()` and `array_map()` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to decode all at once it will fail due to invalid `JSON` because you need an array to hold multiple objects.

Instead you need to decode each line one by one:

```
<?php
$storage_file = 'storage.json';
$storage = file_get_contents($storage_file);
$lines = explode("\n", $storage);

for ($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++)  
{
    $data = json_decode($lines[$i],true);
    print_r($data);
}

?>
```

---

```
<?php
$storage_file = 'storage.json';
$storage = file_get_contents($storage_file);
$lines = explode("\n", $storage);

foreach ($lines as $line)  
{
    $data = json_decode($line,true);
    print_r($data);
}

?>
```

---

```
<?php
$storage_file = 'storage.json';
$storage = file_get_contents($storage_file);
$lines = explode("\n", $storage);

foreach ($lines as $line)  
{
    $data = json_decode($line, true);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        echo "p_name = ".$data[$key]["p_name"]."\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: maybe use foreach instead of for in this case.

Comment: @Alex I agree , `foreach` is always more readable, I included your sugestion

Comment: A silly question , now it shows everything etc etc , how can i call results but names? for example instead of making it show `Array ( [0] => Array ( [p_name] => about [p_about] => [file] => images/1.png ) [1] => Array ( [p_name] => abobo [p_about] => [file] => images/2.png )`
i want to show only name about and file, how do i do that?

Comment: Thanks! You are the best. If possible, tell me , in case i want to delete one of the lines from json file, all i do is `unset($data[2])` in case i want to remove the entire under $i=2 ?

Comment: @EvilNabster sorry I got pulled into a meeting `unset` is only for variable, you will need to add logic in the loop to store the lines you need in an array then use `file_put_content` to keep the desired lines

Comment: @EvilNabster Or _seriously_, start using a database technology. If you want to do file-system based database storage, you can use SQLite

Answer (score 0):

As meda mentioned above the code works perfectly fine, instead I will use `foreach`

```
$storage_file = 'storage.json';
$storage = file_get_contents($storage_file);
$lines = explode("\n", $storage);

foreach ($lines as $str){
    $data = json_decode($str,true);
    print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

am late, but hope, that this answer will be useful to someone.

You have valid json in each file row.
So best solution to use `file()`:

```
$data = array_map(function($row){
  return json_decode($row);
}, file('storage.json'));

print_r($data);
```

- `file` give us array of file rows(so, we don't need to explode it)
- `array_map` applies `json_decode` to each row

For get `pname`'s only:

```
$data = array_map(function($row){
  $a = json_decode($row);
  return $a[key($a)]['pname'];
}, file('storage.json'));

print_r($data);
```

---

**Add**
You use this code for create file:

```
$new_id = count($storage); 
$uid = uniqid(); 
$storage[$uid] = $new_record; 
file_put_contents($storage_file,json_encode($storage), FILE_APPEND);
```

But much better to use this:

```
//get current database:
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);
//...
$uid = uniqid();
$data[$uid] = $new_record;
file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($storage));
```

So we always have valid json with all data.
And always can get it simple as:

```
//get current database:
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);
```